# Android app throws java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10

Tags: android, android-asynctask, iostream

My production android app throws this exception. When I analysed crittercism I noticed that many of my async tasks were not completing. They were hanging on

**ClientSession.java:361**

`responseMessage = (AMessageStrategy) objectInputStream.readObject();`

and

**ClientSession.java:321**

`objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));`.

Did some research on SO and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605153/cannot-create-objectinputstream-with-inputstream-for-a-bluetooth-socket-on-the-a). But did not find any SO question that links RejectedExecution with a Hang issue. Hence this question.

```
org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:65)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:324)
java.io.DataInputStream.readToBuff(DataInputStream.java:159)
java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:375)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2365)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:433)
com.mcruiseon.common.communication.ClientSession$SendQueue.<init>(ClientSession.java:321)

org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)    
dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:461)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:85)
org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:65)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:225)
java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:115)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.checkReadPrimitiveTypes(ObjectInputStream.java:466)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:899)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2262)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2217)
com.mcruiseon.common.communication.ClientSession$SendQueue.run(ClientSession.java:361)
```

I have

- flush just after outputstream create
- creating outputstream before inputstream
- flushing just after write

Still I get the hang, its a random error that occurred 2 months after getting the product on production. Any ideas people ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client, I was creating new sockets without closing the older ones. These sockets were pile'in on. After about 128 sockets android max's out and throws this Exception.

I created a timeout and closed old sockets on inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an donwload on adapter to get one image on each position (in a list), maybe you are repeating on a loop until 128 threads on the Asynctask.
sorry my bad english.

Comment: Nope, I am not using a adapter here.

Comment: then try log for what your code has generating/repeating more then 128 call of asynctask on stack.